# Unexpected Output from reduceByKey function in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on code where I need to aggregate the keys by using reduceBykey function.

//mapToPair code

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> taxiPair = taxiData.mapToPair(

            x->{


                if(!x.isEmpty())
                {

                    String [] split = x.split(",");
                    x=split[9]; //Extracting Index Value 9

                }



           return new Tuple2<String,Integer>("Payment:"+x,1);
        }

    );

    List<Tuple2<String,Integer>> sample = taxiPair.take(10);

    for(Tuple2<String,Integer> t: sample)
    {


        System.out.println(t._1+","+t._2);


    }
```

Above code result as expected. snippet given below. Printing 10 values as a sample.

```
Payment:1,1
Payment:2,1
Payment:1,1
Payment:1,1
Payment:1,1
Payment:1,1
Payment:1,1
Payment:1,1
Payment:1,1
Payment:1,1
```

As per above my understanding says, once reduceByKey is done, it should give the result:

```
Payment:1,9
Payment:2,1
```

However;

//Code reduceByKey

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> taxiReduce = taxiPair.reduceByKey(

     (x,y)-> (y+y)



    );


    List<Tuple2<String,Integer>> sample2 = taxiReduce.collect();

    for(Tuple2<String,Integer> t: sample2)
    {


        System.out.println(t._1+","+t._2);


    }
```

//Output: This is a collective value  from complete dataset, however doesn't seems to be matching with expected value.

```
Payment:3,2
Payment:2,2
Payment:,2
Payment:4,2
Payment:1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Misspint in statement, "x+y" required instead of "y+y" here:

```
  (x,y)-> (y+y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> taxiReduce = taxiPair.reduceByKey(

 (x,y)-> (y+y) );
```

it should be `(x,y)->(x+y);`

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be better to add some context explaining what your code does.